# Is it legal to describe something exactly as "cheese" without asterisks or other qualification if it doesn't contain any dairy?

Tags: united-kingdom, advertisements, false-advertising

Is the marketing statement "our cheese is made of 100% plant ingredients" false advertising and is it legal?

Comment: Often companies will use alternative spellings, like "cheeze" to distinguish, but what if they don't?

Comment: Isn't even cow-produced cheese made of 100% plant ingredients, originally? hmm

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- if you wanna be a smartass, then yes, but in most contexts: no

Comment: Just a general note: the regulations on this kind of question depend heavily on the jurisdiction. You specified UK and the answers are for the UK but they cannot easily be generalized to other jurisdictions.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him No, because of rennet in traditional recipes. Apart from that, the only kind of cheese that doesn't contain dairy products are cheese-head screws.

Comment: Note that the question title "without qualification" does not match the question body, which does have such qualification.

Comment: In the UK at least,  a "cheese" can be a fruit preserve like a jam or jelly (but cloudy and more stiff, so you can cut chunks and slices like a dairy cheese). Apple or Quince cheese goes well with dairy cheeses on a cheeseboard.

Comment: I've seen the pseudo-French term "fauxmage" used for products like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EU there is legislation against using the name "cheese" for non.diary products. This was unsuccessfully challenged in 2017 by company Tofutown:

https://curia.europa.eu/jcms/upload/docs/application/pdf/2017-06/cp170063de.pdf [press release, DE]

https://curia.europa.eu/juris/documents.jsf?num=C-422/16 [full case, EN]

Comment: Is it accurate to say that until there will have been an explicit piece of legislation to overturn the EU precedent, it will still be effective in the UK post-Brexit?

Comment: In the Netherlands we have a product called Pindakaas (Peanut cheese), which is just peanut butter (which does not contain diary). This does not seem to be inline with the legislation

Comment: @SirDuckduck I don't know, "peanut cheese" seems clearly "not cheese" to me...

Comment: The second link is not EN for everyone. It chooses the language according to your location (at least according to your EU country). From what I can read in the Czech version, the terms in the verdict are "milk" and "milk products" or "dairy products", and the implication to other terms mentioned in the original submission in point 3 is not clear to me.

Comment: @TylerH the law allows some exceptions (see footnote 2 of the press release), which are listed in [this document](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32010D0791). "Pindakaas" is listed there, as are other common terms like "coconut milk". This list of exceptions might also be a good addition to the answer.

Comment: @SirDuckduck funny enough, the main reason that they call it like that was because at the time "boter" (butter) was a protected name. You weren't allowed to call things butter unless it was real butter

Answer (score 38):

The [government guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/naming-food-products#customary-and-descriptive-food-names) on naming food products states that if an ingredient is different to what consumers expect, it must be made clear by either:

> - including the ingredient as part of the product’s name
> - stating the ingredient close to the product’s name on the label
>
> For example, if a pesto sauce has been made with parsley instead of the traditional basil, the product must either be:
>
> - called ‘parsley pesto sauce’
> - have the ingredient ‘parsley’ stated next to or directly under the product name

So, it seems that the phrases like "*our cheese is made of 100% plant ingredients*" or "*plant based cheese*" (without quotation marks or asterisks) are compliant with these conditions.

As an aside, the names of [15 cheeses are legally protected](https://www.gov.uk/protected-food-drink-names?keywords=Cheese%20), but this relates to their geographical origins - not the product’s actual ingredients.

Comment: It's interesting that they use the example of "pesto sauce", because in everyday usage in the UK the product usually sold in jars is just labelled and referred to as  "pesto" (unlike in the US), and "pesto sauce" would colloquially refer to a sauce of which pesto was a major ingredient.

Comment: How clear are you on the ingredients side? The product specifications for (e.g) West Country Farmhouse Cheddar state it "is made from cows’ milk produced predominantly 
in the designated area, which may or may not have been pasteurised", which would preclude a vegan substitute (as well as using milk from a different mammal).

Comment: [Gruyere lost their case](https://www.foodandwine.com/news/gruyere-cheese-origin-label-ruling#:~:text=After%20a%20lengthy%20legal%20fight,that%20cheese%20with%20that%20town.)

Comment: @SeanDuggan That's for the US. In Switzerland and the EU, (Swiss) Gruyère and French Gruyère are still protected.

Comment: Would honey be subjected to additional rules, since terms like "clover honey" or "buckwheat honey" generally refer to secretions produced by bees near fields of the indicated plants?

Comment: @ChrisH No, that's pretty much true in the US as well.  Straight pesto as sold in jars can be referred to as either "pesto" or "pesto sauce", but "pesto sauce" might also refer to a sauce containing pesto, though it might be more qualified, e.g. a "pesto cream sauce" or "pesto marinara sauce", when mixed with cream or marinara sauces, respectively.  Anyhow, "pesto" is basically just Italian for "paste" - anything produced by pounding in a pestle. There's no requirement for it to contain basil, that's just the most common usage.

Comment: @Darrel just a small distance in usage frequency then (I'm used to references to "pesto sauce" that clearly mean just "pesto" on cooking.se). Green pesto customarily is based on basil in the UK, but I keep meaning to make nettle pesto in spring.

Comment: Note that there are more than 15 cheeses with legal protection, but they don't all come up with a search for "cheese" - for instance, Single Gloucester cheese is listed just as "Single Gloucester" so doesn't appear in the search you linked to.

Comment: The "designated status" usually is **more** restrictive when it comes to ingredients. E.g. Stilton (which is on the list) is specifically made from cow's milk.

Comment: Note that geographical protections are limited by international jurisdictions.  For example, it is illegal in France (and probably the rest of the EU) to sell a product labeled as "champagne" that does not come from that region of France.  However, that does not stop vineyards *outside* of the EU from calling their sparkling wine "champagne" if they want to.  There are definitely e.g. California vineyards that do this, though others choose to honor the French restriction even though they don't have to.

Comment: This appears to be the definitively correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

I'll limit my answer to the specific example in the question:

> our cheese is made of 100% plant ingredients

This is not false advertising or a deceptive trade practice. It is legal. This is because the statement itself is in the form of a definition of "our cheese", and discloses on its face in a way that avoids any possibility of confusion that it is not "cheese" as defined as an animal. milk curd product.

It is also not false advertising because it uses the word "cheese" in one of its accepted plain meanings.

More generally, words almost always have multiple meanings in the English language. For example, [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheese) has the following six different meanings (of which definition 2 of entry 1 is the sense in which it is used in the quoted material in the question):

> cheese noun (1), often attributive \ ˈchēz  \
>
> Definition of cheese (Entry 1 of 3)
>
> 1a: a food consisting of the coagulated, compressed, and usually
> ripened curd of milk separated from the whey
>
> b: an often cylindrical cake of this food
>
> 2: **something resembling cheese in shape or consistency**
>
> 3: something cheap or shabby : cheesy material //cinematic cheese
>
> cheese verb
>
> cheesed; cheesing
>
> Definition of cheese (Entry 2 of 3) transitive verb
>
> : to put an end to : STOP cheese it —used in the imperative as a
> warning of danger cheese it, the cops
>
> cheese noun (2)
>
> Definition of cheese (Entry 3 of 3) slang
>
> : someone important

Comment: This answer does not address the possibility that consumer product labeling law in the UK might set some restrictions on the use of the word "cheese."  I don't know whether it's the case, but it seems likely (less likely since Brexit, perhaps, but still likely).

Comment: Note the existence for many years of ["fruit cheese"](https://www.allotment-garden.org/recipe/preserves/fruit-butters-cheeses/), essentially a jelly that *resembles cheese in consistency*.

Comment: @phoog Even if there was a consumer labeling law, the full sentence taken as a whole almost surely not offend it, as it might had the word "cheese" been used for a non-dairy product in a label without contemporaneous disclosure of the less common manner in which it was being used.

Comment: In leaving that comment, I had in mind two things: the chocolate labeling controversy with the EU and some recent news about a push (also in the EU) that "steak" must imply "beef" so "tuna steak" should be prohibited. I looked for a cheese regulation analogous to https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2003/1659 for chocolate, but realized that it would be quicker to check a supermarket web site, where I found vegan cheeses are labeled "cheese alternative," "flavor slices," or "dairy-free block," without the word "cheese."  So I suspect that the statement in question may indeed be prohibited.

Comment: It's always the Merriam-Webster dictionary that is linked to for liberal use of language, especially when misrepresenting a traditional meaning.

Comment: @dotancohen can you find an authoritative dictionary that doesn't include the bolded definition?

Comment: That bolded second meaning is rather hilarious in how it's a bit circular, and also in that it actually says that cheese can be used to mean something that's not cheese.

Comment: @dotancohen I chose the Merriam-Webster dictionary for the prosaic reason that it was the first linkable dictionary entry that I found. All of the definitions found there, however, would also be present in the most authoritative dictionary, the Oxford English Dictionary (unabridged), which I could not find in a linkable format.

Comment: @ikkachu Not an uncommon thing in the English language. For example, "bad" is frequently used to mean "good" in vernacular English.

Comment: @phoog Did you actual find an example where "tuna steak" was prohibited or are you just reaching that conclusion through logic. I have no doubt that it would be illegal to call a tuna steak merely "steak" without prominent explanation on a label, but I am doubtful that "tuna steak" would be treated as equivalent to "steak" standing alone for deceptive trade practice type sanctions.

Comment: There was an actual debate about prohibiting "tuna steak."  It seems that the European Parliament declined to pass the legislation: https://www.politico.eu/article/the-war-on-veggie-burgers-not-over-yet-lobby-groups-say/.  Note that this is the EU, so not applicable in the UK, but lots of food regulations passed when the UK was in the EU are still in force.  Relevant to this discussion: "...amendment...No. 171...would restrict terms like 'yogurt style' or 'cheese imitation.' It could even go as far as barring descriptors such as 'lactose-free susbstitute to dairy milk'...."

Comment: It always worries me that "30% less fat cheese" actually means 'contains 1/3 potato starch'. That, to my mind, is pushing the definition as far as it can go.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a lawyer (and thus I may be misinterpreting the regulations), and I do not know if the UK law in this area has changed since leaving the EU, but it appears that this may not be legal due to EU legislation, most of which I believe was transcribed directly into UK law.

[Labelling of milk and milk products](https://www.fsai.ie/legislation/food_legislation/milk_and_milk_products/market_in_milk.html) from the Food Safety Authority of [ireland](/questions/tagged/ireland) states that:

> Regulation (EU) No 1308/2013 defines "Milk" as meaning exclusively the
> normal mammary secretion obtained from one or more milkings without
> either addition thereto or extraction therefrom.

and furthermore:

> Regulation (EU) No 1308/2013 reserves the following names exclusively
> for milk products
>
> (a) the following names used at all stages of
> marketing:
>
> ...
> cheese
> ...

Reading the page further, there is a link to [Decision 2010/791/EU](https://www.fsai.ie/uploadedFiles/Legislation/Food_Legisation_Links/Milk_and_milk_products/Dec2010_791.pdf)  which permits an exemption for *"Fruit cheese (for example, lemon cheese, Damson cheese)"*

However, there does appear to be another exception which may be applicable, although the legalese is so dense in this section I can't fully follow it:

> As an exception, this principle is not applicable to the description of products the exact nature of which is known because of traditional use and/or when the designations are clearly used to describe a characteristic quality of the product.

Comment: I share this opinion, that EU regulations doesn't allow the use of the term 'cheese' for vegan variants of it.
Nevertheless, after the Brexit, possibly it's not part of UK's law anymore. Additionally, I also believe that protected geographical indication (PGI) are not part of UK law anymore. If that's true, you could lable it with Gruyère (like US is doing it)

Comment: If that's the case, EU regulators aren't enforcing it as a quick Google search finds multiple European high street and artisan outlets advertising vegan / dairy- free etc cheese

Comment: @Rick The last exception may apply there. Adding the "dairy-free" designation obviously makes it clear that it's not a dairy product.

Comment: It appears that UK law mimics EU law here, as the EU have accepted it in [Implementing Regulation 2020/2102](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/eur/2020/2102/introduction) (See preamble paragraph 3).

Comment: In the US "Almond Milk" and "Soy Milk" are very common terms.  What's the UK equivalent?

Comment: @Chuu "Almond Drink" and "Soya Drink" (at least on packaging) - in everyday language "Almond Milk" and "Soya Milk" are still used - see also: https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/dairy-free-and-dairy-alternatives/dairy-free-drinks/all

Answer (score 2):

This question is currently tagged [united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom).

In British English the words "cheese" or "curd" simply refer to different stages of a thickened or coagulated liquid.

While the most *common* type of "cheese" with which most people are familiar is a dairy or milk cheese, there **are** other types of cheeses and curds available — most notably various fruit preserves, separate and distinct from jams, marmalades, or chutneys.  For example, Lemon Curd, or Damson Cheese.

As such, the use of the word "cheese" to refer to a a product produced by coagulating plant products is just as valid as using the word "bicycle" to refer to a [Penny-Farthing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny-farthing): it's simply not what **you** are used to, or instinctively think of when you hear the word.

Comment: This is true in colloquial speech but it appears not to be true for "marketing statements" as specified in the question.  Can you point to a commercially available damson cheese?

Comment: @phoog https://www.ninelife.de/products/tracklements-damson-cheese-100g-pack-of-6 though I note that despite the URL the company appears to be American so may not be aware of any regulation that may exist in the EU

Comment: @phoog https://www.fortnumandmason.com/fortnum-s-damson-cheese-120g Here's a UK example.  If you scroll down a bit, you should also find Fig and Quince cheeses too.